# Proof that two basic sequences are convergent to 0 using limit definition.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to resolve two exercises. I think my solutions are OK, but my results are different that results at the end of book. I have to use $|x_n-g|<\epsilon$ inequality to proof convergence. Here $g=0$.

**Ex 1:**
$$x_n=\frac{1}{n!}$$

My try:
$$\frac{1}{n!}\le\frac{1}{n}\Rightarrow\left|\frac{1}{n!}\right|\le\frac{1}{n}\le\epsilon\Rightarrow n \ge\frac{1}{\epsilon}$$

Book solution: $n\ge\sqrt{\frac{2}{\epsilon}}$

I was trying to achieve same result. So I started with following inequality
$$n!=1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots n\ge1+2+3+\cdots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}>\frac{n^2}{2}$$
$$\left|\frac{1}{n!}\right|=\frac{1}{n!}<\frac{1}{\frac{n^2}{2}}=\frac{2}{n^2}\Rightarrow\frac{2}{n^2}<\epsilon\Rightarrow n>\sqrt{\frac{2}{\epsilon}}$$
Is it OK?

**Ex 2:**
$$x_n=\frac{2n}{n^3+1}$$

My try:
$$ \left|\frac{2n}{n^3+1}\right|=\frac{2n}{n^3+1}<\frac{2n}{n^3}=\frac{2}{n^2}$$

And then similar way like before $n>\sqrt{\frac{2}{\epsilon}}$

But this time book's solution is:
$$n>1+\frac{\log{\frac{1}{\epsilon}}}{\log{2}}$$

And here I have no idea how to achieve this result.

Comment: Your solutions are fine.  Don't worry about the answers in the book, which seem overly complicated to me.  Simpler proofs are better proofs.

Comment: The book answers seem almost like they were switched. $n!\geq 2^{n-1}$ means if $$n-1>\log_2(1/\epsilon)=\frac{\log1/\epsilon}{\log 2}$$ then $$\frac1{n!}<\epsilon$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answers are fine.

The book answers seem almost like they were switched. It is probably an editing failure for the book.

We can easily show by induction that  $n!\geq 2^{n-1},$ which means if $$n-1>\log_2(1/\epsilon)=\frac{\log1/\epsilon}{\log 2}$$ then $$\frac1{n!}\leq\frac1{2^{n-1}}<\epsilon$$
So the answer for **Ex 2** appears to be really for **Ex 1,** and, as you’ve noted, vice versa.

But your proof for **Ex 1** is much simpler. Using $n!\geq 2^{n-1}$ is overkill when $n!\geq n$ is enough.